# SQL - Updating a column based on values from another query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Still new to SQL.  My goal is to find the last time stamp event and update the last session column per user.  I created a query that is able to find the last time stamp for each user in the database.  I want to then update `property_last_session_date` based on the `property_user_id`

I'm currently running this off SQLite3 and all 3 columns are defined as Varchar(255)

Here is my code that I'm trying to run.

```
UPDATE tb1
SET
    tb1.property_last_session_date = tt1.property_timestamp
FROM tableEvents tb1
JOIN
    (SELECT tb2.property_user_id, MAX(tb2.property_timestamp)
    FROM tableEvents tb2
    GROUP BY tb2.property_user_id) tt1
ON tb1.property_user_id = tt1.property_user_id
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tb1
SET tb1.property_last_session_date = 
    (SELECT tt1.property_timestamp 
     FROM (SELECT tb2.property_user_id, MAX(tb2.property_timestamp) as property_timestamp
           FROM tableEvents tb2
           GROUP BY tb2.property_user_id) tt1
     WHERE tb1.property_user_id = tt1.property_user_id);
```

It's called a correlated subquery, you may use it in SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE.

Note that this subquery is executed for each row of tb1.

However, MySQL should be smart enough to execute tt1 only once.

This query will update all rows in tb1. There can be some problems with the rows where tb1.property_user_id is null (tb1.property_last_session_date will be set to NULL)

```
UPDATE tb1
SET property_last_session_date = 
    (SELECT prop_time
     FROM (SELECT property_user_id as user_id, MAX(property_timestamp) as prop_time
           FROM tableEvents tb2
           GROUP BY property_user_id) tt1
     WHERE tt1.user_id = property_user_id);
```

Comment: Hi Multisync, I tried your statement above and get a "." syntax error.  I'm using SQLite Expert Personal to run the query on the database.

Comment: @ETam maybe the problem is with "MAX(tb2.property_timestamp) property_timestamp". I added AS between max and alias

Comment: unfortunately it did not work.  Still get the same syntax error?

Comment: @ETam Sorry, it appeared that sqlite3 has some restrictions. I've added an extra update in my answer. May be it will help